# Elasticsearch aggregation on date range

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

suppose following is mapping for employee working :

```
{
    "Project":
    {
         "startDate":{"type":"Date"},
         "endDate":{"type":"Date"},
         "employees":{"type":"keyword"}
    }
}
```

PFB sample data:

```
{
    "Project1":
    {
         "startDate":"2019-07-01",
         "endDate":"2019-07-03"
         "employees":["emp1","emp2"]
    }
},
{
    "Project2":
    {
         "startDate":"2019-07-02",
         "endDate":"2019-07-04"
         "employees":["emp3","emp4"]
    }
}
```

Here employees have list of employees working on that project.
I am unable to write aggregation query which gives me number of employees working on each day. i.e. Employee is working when he is any one or more projects having startdate <= currentDate and endDate >=currentDate.

I want following result:

```
{
    {
     "key":"2019-07-01",
     "EmployeeCount":2
    },
    {
     "key":"2019-07-02",
     "EmployeeCount":4
    },
    {
     "key":"2019-07-03",
     "EmployeeCount":4
    },
    {
     "key":"2019-07-04",
     "EmployeeCount":2
    }
}
```

Can you guide me which  aggregation will help me solve this?

Comment: Use date range aggregation and here is the link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html

Comment: @Maulik Could you share a sample document, the mapping looks confusing, is that the `project` field is of `nested` type? Please clarify

Comment: Hi @Kamal I have updated the questions with sample document and expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid what you are looking for is not possible.

Elasticsearch doesn't support the [`date histogram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) aggregation in such a way to pick up the value from two different date fields, which in your case is `startDate` and `endDate`.

The only way to get what you want is:

- Get the employee count while performing aggregation on `startDate`
- Get the employee count while performing aggregation on `endDate`
- Manage the logic to sum the results in your service layer.

Below is the sample aggregation for calculating the count of employees using `startDate`.

### Sample Index

```
PUT mysampleindex
{  
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {  
       "project":{
         "properties": { 
            "startDate":{  
               "type":"date"
            },
            "endDate":{  
               "type":"date"
            },
            "employees":{  
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents

```
POST mysampleindex/_doc/1
{
    "project":
    {
         "startDate":"2019-07-01",
         "endDate":"2019-07-03",
         "employees":["emp1","emp2"]
    }
}

POST mysampleindex/_doc/2
{
    "project":
    {
         "startDate":"2019-07-02",
         "endDate":"2019-07-04",
         "employees":["emp3","emp4"]
    }
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST mysampleindex/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "mydates": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "project.startDate",
        "interval": "day",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "emp_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "project.employees"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've used [`date histogram`](https://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation with `day` as interval along with the [`value_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) aggregation on `employees` as its child aggregation.

### Query Result:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "mydates" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2019-07-01",
          "key" : 1561939200000,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "emp_count" : {                        <---- Count of employees
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2019-07-02",
          "key" : 1562025600000,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "emp_count" : {                         <---- Count of employees
            "value" : 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can count the employees in similar way for `endDate`(just replace `startDate` with `endDate` in above aggregation query). Once you have both the results, you could perform the addition of what you are looking for in your service layer.

Although technically this doesn't, I just hope this helps!

Comment: it is really a great question. I could not figure out the answer myself but I wish there was a simpler, direct answer to the problem. @Kamal great suggestions +1